# change jquery file, so I would use with other name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jquery, but I want to change the way I call it from `$` or `jQuery` to something else like : **tt**

Example:

```
tt("#selector").click(etc...)
```

instead of:

```
$("#selector").click(etc...)
jQuery("#selector").click(etc...)
```

I know you can do that by changing the jquery file somewhere.

please don't use the **noConflict** function, I need to change the jquery file itself.

Why dont I want to use :
noConflict, and the assiging of jquery to a variable?

because I want to load jquery to the page, but in this page, jquery could be already loaded by the site owner. I don't want to override his jquery, because maybe he uses deprecated functions, and if I load a newer jquery I'll break his javascript.

examle, site html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.1.9.js"></script>


        <script>
            (function() {        
                var ga = document.createElement('script');
                ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
                ga.async = true;
                ga.src = 'http://example.com/myOuterScript.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
<html>
```

and my script that is loaded dynamically: myOuterScript.js
will load jquery, css, and other scripts.

I simply dont want to colide with the jquery in the current site I am in.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a script that loads in other websites that show a bottom bar with features, so I want to use jquery, but not override the site jquery version.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign `jQuery` to whatever variable you like:

```
var tt = jQuery;
var foo = tt('#foo').text();
```

Although I don't see the point of this if the reason is not to avoid a conflict with the `$` variable of another framework.

Answer (score 1):

try **[jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

```
var tt= jQuery.noConflict();

var foo = tt('#foo').text();
```

update by the suggestion   **Rory McCrossan**

```
var tt = jQuery;
var foo = tt('#foo').text();
```

Comment: I don't know why, but the OP said, `please don't use the noConflic function, I need to change the jquery file itself.`

Comment: OP > `please don't use the noConflic function, I need to change the jquery file itself.`

Comment: thanks for your post, but please view my edit, and you will see why I asked not to use that.

Answer (score 1):

As Rory said, you can simply assign jQuery to another variable and use that.  You can also create an enclosure and pass jQuery into that as a parameter, like this...

```
(function(tt) {
    tt("#selector").click(etc...);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thanks for your post, but please view my edit, and you will see why I asked not to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a different alias instead of jQuery to use in the rest of the script.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

// Do something with jQuery
j( "div p" ).hide();

// Do something with another library's $()
$( "content" ).style.display = "none";
```

Comment: OP > `please don't use the noConflic function, I need to change the jquery file itself.`

Comment: thanks for the post, maybe now you will understand why I asked for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement of not using `noConflict` makes no sense to me, but if it's really important, simply do a search and replace in the jQuery source code.

Comment: please review my edit, and you will see why Im asking that. And editing the jquery file is exactly what I want...

Comment: So it's not a programming task. Fire your favorite code editor, and replace every match for "$" and "jQuery" with "tt".

Comment: tried that on jquery 1.10.2 and replaced all jquery to tbQuery, but now I dont know how to change the $, because that overrides as well.